# AngularFireList change retrieving Order

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to get some Data from my Firebase DB, I am listing them with ngfor async, but there are always the most recent at the bottom, but I want them at the Top.

This is my Constructor for the Page:

```
  uid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
  answersRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  allMyAnswers: Observable<any[]>;


  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase, public authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { 

      var path = 'users/' + this.uid + '/answers';

      this.answersRef = db.list(path);
      this.allMyAnswers = this.answersRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
          return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
     });


  }
```

And I am listing them by that:

```
 <div class="aanswer" *ngFor="let myAnswers of allMyAnswers | async">
```

I am googling now since some time but couln'd find a solution that works for snapshotChanges and AngularFireList.

Answer (score 2):

Set the reverse pipe would hit the goal.

**pipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'reverse',
  pure: false
})
export class ReversePipe {
  transform (v) {
    if (v) return v.reverse();

  }
}
```

**your.html**

```
 <div class="answer" *ngFor="let myAnswers of allMyAnswers | async | reverse">
```

And your class got wrong name.

Comment: GREAT! That worked! I also looked for a Pipe, but never thought about adding a second one to async. Thanks!

Comment: But what has the class to do with the ngfor? :) I have answers somewhere else and myanswers are styled like answers.

Comment: it's not effect for your component , but it would let your `aanswer` class unavailable , so correct to `answer` would good work .